# Who's been eating my corn?

Tags: pests, birds

Pretty much all my corn is like this.

[image: partially nibbled corn]

The tassle ends are all eaten. I doubt the stalk would support possums, so maybe rats, or possibly birds?

In NZ near the Zealandia eco-sanctuary

Comment: Looks like rats to me Graham, but difficult to say with certainty as I don’t know your local environment. Perhaps a couple of night inspections (at different times) may reveal the culprit? That is how I determined what creature was eating my tomatoes!

Comment: Curious as to why they left half behind

Comment: Rats eat randomly and what they need at the time. They’re also return customers so check how that damage changes day to day and at what time. If more is eaten every day and it appears the damage was caused overnight, I’d almost guarantee the culprit is rat. The lower half of my once promising crop of “Beefsteak” tomatoes were eaten in portions over a period of nights until I decided to bring the pot inside (a backbreaking and unsustainable practice).

Comment: I'll put some rat traps out.

Comment: If you are in New Zealand it might be Rat-Monkeys (*Simian raticus*)... :P

Answer (score 1):

Crows, they are horrid to eat corn exactly in this manner. Notice your corn stalks are still upright and not been bent over by a heavy animal. Also notice the corn has not been taken big chunks from, it's been pecked out with a sharp beak. I promise you it's them danged Ole Crows.

Comment: Interesting idea but most rook colonies have been destroyed in eradication programs. I don't think I've seen a crow where I live.